# How to replace the contents of a button when the page has a width of 768px?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How to replace the contents of a button when the page has a width of 768px?

```
<a title"Reserve seu Ingresso" class="btn btn-blue" href="#reservar">
    <i class="fa fa-ticket 1x"></i>
    Reserve seu ingresso
</a>
```

I have this button, and I want take off the content when the page has a width of 768. How can I do that?

I was trying to use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn {
    content: "";
   }
}
```

Comment: Your use of media queries is fine - just to let you know. :)

Comment: While you _can_ do this using pseudoelements and the content property (as in the text lives only in CSS), you should either hide or show via CSS, or do this with javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, CSS's `content` property only works on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. You cannot use it to alter the text found within a HTML document.

Your best option here would be to wrap the text in a `span` element:

```
<a class="btn btn-blue" ... >
    <i ... ></i>
    <span>Text here</span>
</a>
```

Then hide the `span` element by setting its `display` property to `none`:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .btn span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, the `content` property works within pseudo elements. So another approach would be to set the text as an `:after` pseudo content of the `<a>` tag, so you would be able to clear it with the media query:

```
<a title="Reserve seu Ingresso" class="btn btn-blue" href="#reservar">
    <i class="fa fa-ticket 1x"></i>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.btn:after {
    content: "Reserve seu ingresso";
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    a.btn:after {
        content: "";
    }
}
```